# make inputfield active on click of radio button

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery

I have one radio button and one inputfield..I am trying to achieve something like.if i click on the radio button , the input field should get active and user should be able to enter the value..If the radio button is not selected ..the field should be availabe but it should be disabled.

I have written something like below..but its not working

```
<input onclick ="document.getelementbyid('datepurchased').disabled =true;" type = "radio" name = "abc"></input>   
<apex:inputField id="datepurchased" value="{!lstRMA[0].Date_Purchased__c}"/>
```

can someone help?

Comment: ya sure !! are u getting any error ?

Comment: no error :( but it doesnot work

Comment: Can you use checkbox instead of radio button ?

Comment: i tried with checkbox..but still its not working

Comment: wait i'll provide you code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24747/discussion-between-aryan-kapoor-and-ankita-singh).

Comment: Its not possible..its blocked here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example with Radio button. On load the input field is disabled, when you click on radio button the input field will enable.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="contact" extensions="radioActionCtrl"  >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:selectRadio >
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!changeInputState}" rerender="opPanelName"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="" itemlabel="Option1"/>
        </apex:selectRadio>       
        <apex:outputPanel id="opPanelName">
            <apex:inputField value="{!contact.firstName}" id="NameInput" required="false"/>
            <script>
                document.getElementById('{!$Component.NameInput}').disabled = {!disableInput};
            </script>
        </apex:outputPanel>            
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller Extension**

```
public class radioActionCtrl {
    public Boolean disableInput {get; set;}
    public radioActionCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        disableInput = true;
    }    
    public void changeInputState(){
        disableInput = false;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example...

```
<apex:pageBlock id="tBlock"> 
        <apex:outputLabel value="Checkbox" for="theCheckbox" />  
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!customObject.CheckBox__c}" id="theCheckbox">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="tBlock"/>  
            </apex:inputCheckbox>   

            <apex:outputLabel value="Enter Data Here" />  
            <apex:inputText value="{!customObject.TextField__c}" disabled="false" rendered="{!(customObject.CheckBox__c == true)}"/>  
            <apex:inputText value="{!customObject.TextField__c}" disabled="true" rendered="{!(customObject.CheckBox__c != true)}"/>  

            <!-- If you only want a field to show up when you check the box See below -->  
            <apex:inputText value="{!customObject.TextField__c}" rendered="{!(customObject.CheckBox__c == true)}"/>  
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

For additional information on the  tag, you can go to the following link as well:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputLabel.htm

I also use these pages for additional Visualforce reference:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_compref_outputLabel.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_compref_outputLabel.htm|SkinName=webhelp

I hope this helps out.

Thanks!

Aryan!

Comment: what do you mean by !customObject.CheckBox__c

Comment: dear your checkbox field value which will come from object

Comment: i dont have checkbox_c in  my custom object then how come it will come from database?

Comment: than how will u get checkbox value ?

Comment: i have just rendered the checkbox on the vf page.when i click on radio button or checkbox..the input field should get enabled

Comment: okie!!! so do 1 thing take boolean variable on ur controller side and bind that within  **<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!customObject.CheckBox__c}" id="theCheckbox">**  this statement

Comment: but still it will throw error for this statement 
!customObject.CheckBox__c..am i right?